# How to create DataTemplate from UserControl instance?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, datatemplate

**Question**

Basically I would like to do the following but it seems that I cannot:

```
UserControl myControl = new UserControl();
DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate(myControl);
```

The question: Is it possible to construct a DataTemplate from UserControl instance? If not, are there any other possible solutions?

---

**Real problem**

I'm working on a project where majority of UI views are simple static Word-like documents (e.g some text fields and maybe some images, nothing too fancy). Because most of persons working on this project are not coders we have designed very simple in-house markup language for UI generation. An example of markup of simple view is following:

```
First name: [Person.FirstName]
Last name: [Person.LastName]
Address: [Person.Address.Street], [Person.Address.City]
```

Now these templates are loaded at runtime and usercontrols are created based on them. In this case one usercontrol would be created and it would contain simply couple of stack panels and text blocks so that resulting control would look a bit like text document. XAML equivalent would be something like:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="First name: "/>
        <TextBlock Text={Binding Person.FirstName}
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        ...
    </StackPanel>
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

Then, I started to implement support for lists but couldn't think of a way how to do that. In theory it is simple and I came up with following syntax (+ XAML equivalent):

```
[List Customers]
First name: [Person.FirstName]
Last name: [Person.LastName]
Address: [Person.Address.Street], [Person.Address.City]
[EndList]

->

<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                [Insert code from previous XAML example here]
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

But I can't do that because it seems that I cannot construct DataTemplate directly from UserControl **instance**. There would be no problems if my UserControls were **types**, but they are not.

One possible solution is that I could bind *ItemsControl.Items* directly to list of UserControls (instead of binding to *ItemsSource* and *ItemTemplate*) but this is sub-optimal in our case for couple of reasons. I would be willing to try some other solutions first!

**Update**

For clarification: all I have is plain instance of UserControl class which contains the content I need. E.g.

```
UserControl control = new UserControl();
var panel = new StackPanel();
panel.Children.Add(...);
panel.Children.Add(...);
control.Content = panel;
// How to use that control as ItemTemplate for ItemsControl?
// It seems that it is not possible directly but I want to
// know what my options are.
```

I don't have class for it because I'm constructing it at run-time and I don't want to create new type dynamically by emiting IL code because it is way too painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I understand your problem now. I don't think there is an easy way (one or two lines of code) to create a datatemplate from a UserControl instance.

But to solve your problem I see two directions:

1. At the point where an usercontrol is created, create a datatemplate instead and use that. It will be cumbersome, with nested FrameworkElementFactories. I have never done that, and the MSDN documentation says that you may encounter some limitations you cannnot do compared to datatemplates in Xaml. But if it is simple it must be doable. There used to be a codeproject article by Sacha Barber you could use as a guidance (if needed).
2. You pack the creation of the UserControl in a method called `private UserControl createMyUserControl(){}`

And do something like this:

```
    ItemsControl itemsControl = new ItemsControl();
    foreach (var customer in Customers) 
    {
       var usercontrol = createMyUserControl(...);
       usercontrol.DataContext = customer;
       itemsControl.Items.Add(usercontrol);
    }
```

Second option is less elegant in my opinion, so I would check out the option 1 first.

[WPF: How to create Styles in code/and magical Content (see section at the end for extensive sample of a DataTemplate in Code behind)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29699/WPF-How-to-create-Styles-in-code-and-magical-Conte)

Comment: The first option sounds fine and I'll give it a try. Thank you! I had already thought about second option but as you said, it's far less elegant.

Answer (score 7):

Creating a datatemplate from Code behind goes like this:

```
FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(MyUserControl.GetType());
DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();
dt.VisualTree = factory;

yourItemsControlInstance.ItemTemplate = dt;
```

A datatemplate is a definition of controls to be built at runtime, that is way this construction with a ElementFactory. You do not want the same instance of the UserControl for every item in your ItemsControl.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this but as I mentioned in my question, there is no type I could pass to FEF. I am looking some way to do similar thing when I have UserControl instance (clone, extract information to create a type etc.)

Comment: You want to extract information to create a type? You have the type information of your user control to create an instance. Please specify what info is missing if you do the above?

Do you mean that you don't know the type at compile time? You can get the type of a runtime instance with GetType().

Comment: Ok it seems that I was not clear enough. I have updated the question. Basically, all I have is plain instance of UserControl class, not separate type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace `UserControl` with the `ContentControl`. 
Just set the content of the `ContentControl` to the desired template and use it as ItemTemplate for the ItemsControl.